# How to publish my visual studio 2012 VB.NET Website to Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have .Net 4.5 web application and trying to publish the site to Azure account.. I did all the settings and creating the new website in azure and downloading the .projectsettings file to my project folder . But when i right click my project ans publish , its not options to import the file. Please see the attached image. I am new to Azure and this is my first project..

[image]
Thanks,

Comment: The issue got fixed by installing Microsoft Azure SDK for VS2012 .

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1) Close VS 2012.

2) Downaload and then install Azure SDK for VS 2012. here is the download link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44938

3) Re-open your project and publish your app.